# No vibration when using local notifications

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to fire a localnotification using

```
// notification.alertBody = @"";

notification.hasAction = NO;
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
```

The notification fires correctly when I set it up this way, it adds the badge and plays a sound, but there's no vibration unless I display alertBody.

Is there any way to get a vibration to go along with the sound and not show an alert?

Comment: See this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084175/vibrate-and-sound-to-localnotifications