# Vibrate and sound to LocalNotifications

Tags: objective-c, ios, notifications

How I add vibrate and sound to LocalNotifaction

code:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

NSDate *firedate = settime.date;
[notification setFireDate:firedate];
[notification setAlertBody:@"הלכה יומית"];
[notification setAlertAction:@"הלכה"];



[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the sound:

```
notification.soundName = @"yourSound.aiff" ;   // see also UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
```

But vibration is outside your control:

> Unfortunately, if you want a sound, you can't disable vibration unless the user has went into the General Settings and disabled vibration themselves.
>   [-shabzco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9451489/1523962)

> The UILocalNotification API lets you set the system default sound, choose a sound, or have no sound, and if you have some sound, it will vibrate under the right circumstances (i.e., the user has enabled vibration). But beyond that, you have no control over whether vibration occurs or how long it lasts.
>   [-yuji](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9320512/1523962)